# Text annotation scaling

Tags: qgis

I have seen other people mention the issue of text annotation scaling which does not match the scale on the map once you convert the document into a pdf. Does anyone know if there is a way to resolve this in QGIS 3.6.1? I have tried to increase the font to a crazy size but it still looks small on the pdf. If I look up the 'Item' menu, there is no option to change rendering as suggested in previous blogs. Any suggestions to help a novice like me?

Comment: What unit do you use for your font size?

Comment: *Text annotation* font can only be sized in "points" (eg, 8-point font).

Answer (score 2):

To clarify, a Text Annotation looks like this:

[image]

You can create a Text Annotation from the buttons on the right side of the Attributes toolbar.

I think the "[Annotation Tools](https://docs.qgis.org/3.4/en/docs/user_manual/introduction/general_tools.html#annotation-tools)" feature is not very widely used. It's also rather difficult to talk about, because "annotation text" just sounds like you're talking about a regular label, which leads to confusion like the comment posted above (which I mistakenly up-voted before I remembered that an annotation is a distinct thing).

When not many people are using a feature, it can have bugs that go un-detected or un-fixed for a long time. That seems to be the case here.

You can check on the status of the relevant bug report, [Text annotation scale wrong in print layouts](https://issues.qgis.org/issues/20300). This bug was posted 6 months ago, and updated 3 months ago with this note:

> Seeing this issue in 3.4.4 still - also tested in 3.2 and 3.0 and seeing the same issue. Text Annotation is the correct size in view window and in print layout but is tiny and unreadable when exported to pdf/png. Can someone have a look, please, as the initial report doesn't look like it's been actioned. Title on report needs to be amended to reflect that it is the exported item that is the issue, not the print layout scaling.

**Workarounds:**

At this point I think your best workaround is still to make the font size **enormous** before exporting. Like, 72 points or bigger. Yes, this is annoying and inconvenient.

If you use text annotations a lot, it might be worth doing a more involved workaround. Create a point layer with the annotation text in a text field, and set up symbology that mimics the text annotation graphic.

Basic multiline label with a rectangular background:

[image]

Same as above, plus an additional symbol layer, a geometry generated line connecting the rectangle to the point:

[image]

using this expression for the geometry generator: `make_line(make_point(x($geometry)+50000,y($geometry)+9000), $geometry, make_point(x($geometry)+50000,y($geometry)-9000))`. Note that the numerical values are in the distance units of the layer, and you'll need to change them whenever you change the zoom level.

You could also set up a more complicated expression where these numbers depend on the map scale, calculated from the `canvasheight()` and `canvaswidth()` functions.

Answer (score 0):

Has there been any development on this issue? I am having the same problem coupled with scaling issues between a Microsoft surface and external display.

I managed to solve the scaling issues but the knock on appears to be the issue described here.

Would love to see a fix for this.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/237620)